# android post gzip

Tags: android, wcf, gzip

Trying to implement gzip on an Android project to reduce client data charges. All devices connect to a WCF webservice and IIS is now sending compressed data back to the devices as expected. Now I need to work out how to post back gzipped xml data modified on the android device.
The device code is as follows

```
     httpsURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
     httpsURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
     httpsURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
     httpsURLConnection.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT);
     httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
     httpsURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
     httpsURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Encoding", "gzip);
     httpsURLConnection.connect();

     GZIPOutputStream gzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream((httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream())));
     gzipOutputStream.write(_xmlText.getBytes());
     gzipOutputStream.flush();
     gzipOutputStream.finish();
     gzipOutputStream.close();
```

Running Wireshark on webserver shows the gzip packets and decompresses them to show the correct data from the device.
The problem is that the WCF web service does not seem to recognise the data - the error is XmlException - The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
Which makes me think that the data is still compressed and WCF cannot handle gzip - which I seem to remember reading about previously. Do I then need to create a message decoder in .net to handle the gzip compression? Was this hopefully addressed in .net 4.5?

Any help with these questions appreciated.